# How to create an endpoint which takes a path, load the image and serve it to the client

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, bufferedimage

I want to serve an image to a client by converting it to a byte but for some reason byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() is empty. I get a response status of 200 which means it is served. I looked at various documentations on reading an image file from a directory using BufferedImage and then converting BufferedImage to a byteArray from oracle https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html but for some reason byteArray is still empty

This controller

```
@GetMapping(path = "/get/image/{name}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> displayImage(String name) throws IOException {
        String photoPathFromDatabase = productRepository.findPhotoByName(name);
        Path path = Paths.get(photoPathFromDatabase);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();



        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(path.toFile()); // Reading the image from path or file
        String fileType = Files.probeContentType(path.toFile().toPath()); // Getting the file type
        ImageIO.write(image, fileType, byteArrayOutputStream); // convert from BufferedImage to byte array
        byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(fileType))
                .body(bytes);
    }
```

After I debugged the method
[image]

Comment: The reason why the code don't work: `filetype` contains a MIME type for your image, `"image/jpeg"`, but the `ImageIO.write` method expects the format name, which is `"JPEG"`. However, unless you want to do on-the-fly pixel processing, the better choice is to do as @SomeoneBadAtJava suggests, just copy the binary data directly. It's easier, faster and cheaper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the bytes of the file directly, rather than use an excessive amount of methods from different classes. This can be done with the class `java.nio.file.Files`.

```
byte[] contentBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path); //Throws IOException
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the file extension is not getting set properly.

You can create a new method to get the file extension or you can use `FilenameUtils.getExtension` from Apache Commons IO.

```
public static Optional<String> getExtensionByStringHandling(String filename) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(filename)
            .filter(f -> f.contains("."))
            .map(f -> f.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
}
```

then change your ImageIO to take this file extention.

```
String fileExtention= getExtensionByStringHandling(file.getName()).orElseThrow(()->new RuntimeException("File extension not found"));
ImageIO.write(image, fileExtention, byteArrayOutputStream);
```